# Hangman game guessing letters in c ++

Tags: c++

Hangman game guessing letters in c ++

A first player must enter a secret word, and the second player must enter letters in order to guess the word entered by the first player and the game ends when the second player guesses or has 5 wrong attempts, that is, enter 5 letters that do not belong to the word.

I was trying to make this code, it reads the secret word, it forms the respective "_" according to the length of the entered word but the letter is not replaced and it is constantly repeated that the letter has already been entered even if it is false, please help. I can't make the code correctly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string palabra = " ", letra = " ", guion = " _ ", letraUsada = " ", letraNoUsada = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int vidas = 5, lugarLetra = 0, longitud = 0;
    char letraReemplazada = 'N', finJuego = 'N';

    cout << "Ingresa la palabra secreta: ";
    getline(cin, palabra);
    system("cls");

    for (int i = 1; i <= palabra.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << guion;
        longitud++;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Empezemos a adivinar " << endl;
    cout << endl;

    while (finJuego == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Ingresa una letra: ";
        cin >> letra;
        cout << endl;
        lugarLetra = letraNoUsada.find(letra, 0);
        if (lugarLetra != string::npos)
        {
            letraNoUsada.replace(lugarLetra, 1, "*");
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "La letra " << letra << " ya ha sido ingresada. Escoja otra letra" << endl;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < palabra.length(); x++)
        {
            if (palabra.substr(x, 1) == letra)
            {
                guion.replace(x, 1, letra);
                letraReemplazada = 'Y';
            }
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So.. what changes `finJuego` in your `while` loop? It's initialized to `'N'`, the condition says "keep going until it is no longer 'N'" and *nothing* in the loop actually changes it.

Comment: @WhozCraig finJuego must change when the errors are equal to 5 or the second player guesses the word

Comment: Then modify your code so that it does just that - changes when the errors are equal to 5 or the second player guesses the word.

Comment: @KenWhite and how I do it?

Comment: By writing the code to change `finJuego` when the error count gets to 5 or the second user guesses the word. Where do you count errors? After increasing that count, check to see if it's equal to 5 or not, and do what you need to do if it does. The same goes for when the second user guesses the word - when that happens, do whatever you need to do.

Comment: guion is " _ " and then you `cout << guion;` for each letter in palabra.  But when you replace with `guion.replace(x, 1, letra);` which makes no sense - for example: lets say palabra = "GOODBYE" and the letter entered is "E" and then when you do the replacement `palabra.substr(x, 1) == letra` is true at x=6 so then you `guion.replace(x, 1, letra);` with x=6 but guion is only 3 characters long.  Instead of printing guion once for each letter in palabra you probably want to make a string of underscore characters the same length as palabra.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah oh right, how could I make guion = "_" have all the characters of the word and can be replaced properly?

Comment: @yipos  Start with guion empty and then add a "_" to it for each letter in palabra.  Then when you print the unguessed word print each character surrounded by a space.

Comment: This is how I might do it: https://onlinegdb.com/Bkelj_XWd  Please forgive the Spanish - I used google translate...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Hi. What do you think, in which way could you change your comment into a contrubution to StackOverflow according to the concepts and ideas in this community? And what are the reasons that you did differently?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to spend hours writing an actual answer that comprehensively answers the question.  I might do that when I have time.  But spending a couple minutes writing an example does not make a quality answer - so it really is a comment until there is time to make it into a real answer.